# A complex integral with Cauchy integral formula

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, contour-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

> Let
>   $$f(z) =  \frac{e^{iz}}{z^2(z^2+1)}$$
>   Determine value of the following integral which $C$ is a simple closed curve enclosing $0$ and $i$(and not $-i$).
>   $$I = \oint_C f(z)dz$$

Using residue theorem, I found that $I = -\pi e^{-1} - 2\pi$ but I'm interested in other methods. For instance Cauchy integral formula if it's applicable or deformation of path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $I=\int_C \frac {e^{iz}} {z^{2}}dz-\int_C \frac {e^{iz}/(z+i)} {(z-i)}dz$. Can you evaluate each of the two terms by Cauchy's Intgeral Formula?

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot. Do you know other ways?